# MIPS - checking for overflow on an addiu operation

Tags: assembly, architecture, overflow, mips

For an assignment, I have to compute Fibonacci numbers and store them into an array until the most recent Fibonacci number creates an overflow. Here is what I have so far:

```
.data
FBN: .space 400     
     .align 2       
NUM_FBN: .space 4   
         .align 2       

.text
.globl main 

main:
  la $s0, FBN 
  li $t0, 0 #Fib(0)
  li $t1, 1 #Fib(1) 

  sw $t0, 0($s0) 
  sw $t1, 4($s0)    
  li $t2, 1 # index of most recently computed fib number


loop: 
  lw $t0, 0($s0) 
  lw $t1, 4($s0) 

  addu $t3, $t1, $t2
```

At this point, if there is no overflow, I store $t3 into 8($s0), increment the array source address and continue the loop. However, we're instructed only to use addiu or addu instructions, and to assume the numbers are signed. I'm confused as to how unsigned addition is done on signed numbers, and what happens when the result is out of range. How can I go about checking for overflow in this situation?

Comment: It works just fine for signed too. The wonders of two's complement. As for checking overflow, you should verify that the result is not negative (if you are adding two positive numbers, which applies to fibonacci).

Comment: So basically I just have to figure out if the most significant bit is 1?

Comment: Yes, that's one way to check it.

Comment: If your numbers are all signed positive, you can treat them like 31-bit unsigned integers, and the high bit is your carry-out "flag" (assuming both inputs had that bit cleared on input to `addu` / `addui`).  You can of course test the sign bit using a signed compare for less than 0.

Comment: I got it to work using the 'BLTZ' instruction. Thank you both.